# Cant Send Value To PHP String With AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

What is the actual deal in the Data part ?

```
<form id="form" name="form">
<input type="text" name="textname" id="textname">
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="post();">
</form>

function post()
{
  var textname = $('#textname').val();

    $.ajax
    ({
      url: 'post.php',
      data: {testurl:textname},
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data)
        {
          $('#test').html(data);
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
  }
```

And the post.php

```
<?php
      echo "test";

      $testurl = $_POST['textname'];

      echo var_dump($testurl); 
?>
```

> Echo Test is working but Output for the var_dumb is NULL string(0) - Empty String

Comment: there's no `$_POST['textname']`. in your data you put the value of `textname` in `testurl` so you should be looking for `$_POST['testurl']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand one simple thing, in ajax call the data parameter contains the

> key : value

pair in it.

Means if your data part is some thing like:

```
data: {
   var1 : val1,
   var2 : val2,
}
```

than in your php function you can get these values using its keys 
i.e. var1, var2.

Comment: Yea i figure it out like 10 seconds after i create this post lol, Need some sleep i guess :S Thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

You made the mistake:

**Change the following**

```
  $testurl = $_POST['textname'];
```

**into**

```
  $testurl = $_POST['testurl'];
```